# Panel data in DolphinDB

Tags: panel, panel-data, dolphindb

I have the following table in DolphinDB:

```
n=1000000
t1=table(rand(`a`b`c,n)as ID, rand(2017.08.16..2018.09.15,n) as date ,rand(10.0,n) as price)
```

What I am trying to do is transpose the table into a panel data that all dates are in one column, for example:

```
date        a       b       c
2017.08.16  1.1246  4.6269  2.3019
2017.08.17  7.8525  9.7178  2.916741
...
```

Is there an efficient way to do it in DolphinDB？

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
panel(t1.date,t1.ID,t1.price, 2017.08.16..2018.09.15)
```

another way:

```
select price from t1 pivot by date,ID
```